# JQuery get element from a string problem

Tags: jquery

Sorry for such a simple question but I can't seem to find the solution.

I am trying to fade in and out some divs.

Divs have an ID of "div1", "div2", "div3".

My code is:

```
var Divs = new Array("div1", "div2", "div3");
```

I want to fade out one div and then fade in the next on top of it.

I have a setinterval that runs every 5 seconds and checked it works.

Inside it is this code:

```
 $(Divs[1]).fadeOut(1000);
 $(Divs[2]).fadeIn(1000);
```

However nothing happens when the timer method is ran. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Identify them by their ID property. The selector has to look like `$('#ID').action(args);` and I believe your selector would only select tags of type `<div1></div1>`, `<div2></div2>` etc

```
$('#'+Divs[1]).fadeOut(1000);
```

Comment: I see, I am getting somewhere now but I can't get my div to fadeout.. any ideas? I'm a total jquery beginner by the way...

Comment: Can I assume your stuff is wrapped in `$(document).ready(function() { <yourcode> })` ? Or can you start another question and post your source?

Comment: Hmm the code above should work, it fades fine if I put the ID in manually, but I guess it's not reading from my array properly. I'm not using [1] though I am using a variable to store 1. Could that be the reason?

Comment: var CurrentDiv = 1; ... and ... $("#" + Divs[CurrentDiv]).fadeOut(1000);

Comment: I wouldn't think so--the array syntax looks good. Even Divs[x] should produce the correct selector string.

Comment: Can you try with single quotes for grins and giggles? I have seen it work in the past, but it's unjustified as far as I can tell.

Comment: All fixed now, thanks for your help, typical me being a noob...:)

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector is looking for elements by tag name. In order to search by ID you need the `#` prefix. Here's the full reference:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Try this instead:

```
var Divs = ["#div1", "#div2", "#div3"];
```

Comment: Isn't this effectively the same answer that **David** gave earlier?

Comment: Yes. Stack Overflow doesn't always notify you that there're new answers while you're composing yours.